# Opening target="_blank" links with Xamarin.Forms WebView

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, android-webview

I have recently encountered an issue with links having the `target` attribute set to `_blank`. Tapping on them has no effect. The `WebView` does not load the linked page.

Searching around I found this solution: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12917 which is setting `SetSupportMultipleWindows(false)`. More specifically [the suggestion is](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12852) to insert the following line of code: `webView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);`.

Trying that I get the following error: `Error CS1061 'WebView' does not contain a definition for 'Settings' and no accessible extension method 'Settings' accepting a first argument of type 'WebView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Is there a way to overcome the error?

Comment: it sounds like you are trying to call `Settings` on the `WebView` class, and not the instance of `WebView`

Comment: No, that's the line as offered in the second link. I do it for the instance in my Xamarin.Forms code.

Comment: hmm, that appears to be a setting on the Android WebView that you would need to set in a custom renderer

Comment: Isn't the setting accessible in any way via the Xamarin.Forms code? If not do I have to implement a `HybridWebView` in order to use a custom renderer? And my final question where exactly do I implement the custom renderer code? In my Xamarin.Forms project or in the Android project?

Comment: I don't know.  That's just based on a casual glance at the github issue you linked to and the docs.  Custom renderers are created in the platform project.  All you should really need to do is override that one setting.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: you might be able to do it with an Effect: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After many tries towards the wrong direction I found the line of code that worked for me. In the override of the `OnElementChanged` method in the `Custom Webview Renderer` this is the code that makes the opening of links with `target=_blank` attribute possible:

`Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);`

`SetSupportMultipleWindows;` should be set to ***false***, not to ***true*** as it has been suggested.

Comment: Do you have any good examples of this implementation. I am struggling with this right now and I have no idea what the Custom Webview Render is.

Comment: Just use the code of the answer given below for the `Custom Renderer` but change **true** to **false**, as I have suggested. (Create the Custom Renderer in the Android project). Also in the shared project create a new file with C# code that implements the `HybridWebView` as **[described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview)**.

Comment: Thank you so much. I hate when minor issues require overkill solutions. Looks like this is the only option though! Glad to see I am not the only one dealing with this though.

Answer (score 1):

You could add support for multiple windows in **OnElementChanged** of **Hybrid renderer** with code:

```
Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
```

edit:

```
public class MyWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public MyWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
            }

        }

    }

    public class MyWebChromeClient: WebChromeClient
    {
        public override bool OnCreateWindow(Android.Webkit.WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)
        {

            if(!isDialog)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I have implemented both the Custom `WebView` and the `Renderer`. I get the following error: `CS0115 'HybridWebViewRenderer.OnCreateWindow(WebView, bool, bool, Message)': no suitable method found to override`. Any idea?

Comment: sorry about the late reply, I updated the answer

Comment: No problem. I have installed a plugin `WebView` that seems to solve the problem. Unfortunately, I'm getting `Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported` error out of nowhere and I have to solve it before continuing with my implementation.

Comment: if you get solution you can update your question with your answer

Comment: In which file does the override of the `OnCreateWindow` takes place: `public override bool OnCreateWindow`?

Comment: check edit, in MyWebChromeClientn class which subclass the WebChromeClient

Comment: In which file do you put these lines of code:
 `Android.Webkit.WebView newWebView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
        view.AddView(newWebView);
        Android.Webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (Android.Webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.Obj;
        transport.WebView = newWebView;
        resultMsg.SendToTarget();
        return true;`

They obviously aren't in `public class MyWebChromeClient: WebChromeClient`.

Comment: Another issue. I update the Uri (with another one with a new query string), but the content in the WebView stays the same, although the content should change depending on the query. I even run Reload method for the WebView, but the content still stays the same. Should I change something in the Renderer?

Comment: just add set the onElementchanged as the edit part shows, as for your new issue, add a new propertychanged event like this link shows https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1565bbc2-3bcb-468e-8e70-1f44b747d19c/hybridwebview-is-not-navigating-to-new-uri-when-the-uri-property-is-changed?forum=xamarinforms

Comment: Well, I added the `PropertyChanged` listener and that fixed the issue of the update of the `WebView`'s content. Still no luck with opening the links though. Tapping on links in the `Custom  WebView` has no effect.

Comment: Well you got this wrong. The right line of code is:
`Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);` I just changed `true` to `false` and links open now! Thanks for all the support though!