# CS0115 'HybridWebViewRenderer.OnCreateWindow(WebView, bool, bool, Message)': no suitable method found to override - Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, webview, android-webview, custom-renderer

I am trying to implement this solution offered as an answer here: [Opening target="_blank" links with Xamarin.Forms WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427075/opening-target-blank-links-with-xamarin-forms-webview/71434614#71434614)

In the **Android project** I have created a custom renderer which has these code excerpts:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), typeof(MyApp.controls.HybridWebViewRenderer))]


public class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        }
      
    }
```

In my **shared project** I have created a `HybridWebView` which has among others these excerpts of code:

```
public class HybridWebView : WebView
    {
       
        public override bool OnCreateWindow(Android.Webkit.WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Android.OS.Message resultMsg)
        {
            Android.Webkit.WebView newWebView = new Android.Webkit.WebView(_context);
            view.AddView(newWebView);
            Android.Webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (Android.Webkit.WebView.WebViewTransport)resultMsg.Obj;
            transport.WebView = newWebView;
            resultMsg.SendToTarget();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

This gives as a result the following error:

`CS0115 'HybridWebViewRenderer.OnCreateWindow(WebView, bool, bool, Message)': no suitable method found to override`

Any idea how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned,we do not need to override the OnCreateWindow in custom renderer in Target project.Also, please take care of the **OnElementChanged** method in Custom Webview.We need set **SetSupportMultipleWindows** to **true**,enabled JS,set SetWebChromeClient, set WebViewClient,set AddJSInterface and last but not least, **LoadUrl** for the webview.

Below is the code snippet for your reference:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HybridWebView), 
typeof(HybridWebViewRenderer))]
namespace AppHybridWebView.Droid
{
    public  class HybridWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {

        public HybridWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
                Control.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
                Control.SetWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
                Control.SetWebViewClient(new JavascriptWebViewClient(this, $"javascript: {JavascriptFunction}"));
                Control.AddJavascriptInterface(new JSBridge(this), "jsBridge");
                Control.LoadUrl($"file:///android_asset/Content/{((HybridWebView)Element).Uri}");//LoadUrl
            }

        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                ((HybridWebView)Element).Cleanup();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

    }

    public class MyWebChromeClient : WebChromeClient
    {
        public override bool OnCreateWindow(Android.Webkit.WebView view, bool isDialog, bool isUserGesture, Message resultMsg)
        {

            if (!isDialog)
            {
                return true;
            }

            return base.OnCreateWindow(view, isDialog, isUserGesture, resultMsg);
        }
    }
}
```

Code in xaml:

```
<local:HybridWebView x:Name="hybridWebView" Uri="index.html" />
```

Comment: Should I override the `LoadUrl`? Whenever I do it I get a blank page in the custom `WebView`.  When I don't the website loads fine, but `target=_blank` links won't open.
Code from the custom `WebView`:        ` public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "Uri",  returnType: typeof(string),
declaringType: typeof(HybridWebView),  defaultValue: default(string));
public string Uri  {get { return (string)GetValue(UriProperty); } set { SetValue(UriProperty, value); }}`
Here from the renderer: `Control.LoadUrl($"{((HybridWebView)Element).Uri}");`

Comment: You don't need to override the LoadUrl.You need to save the index.html in Assets/Content/index.html and load it.BTW, you can refer to official sample:https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/HybridWebView for more details.

Comment: I used a readily available plugin `Webview` in the meantime, which I believe resolves my issues, but now I'm getting `Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported error` out of nowhere and I have to solve it before continuing with my implementation.

Comment: Well I removed the nuget plugin. It was the cause of the error. I just tried your proposed solution again, with the difference that I'm loading a page from the Web not from a local file. It doesn't work. The page loads, but links on the page that have the `target=_blank` do not open. That's exactly the behavior I had with `WebView` before implementing `HybridWebView` class and a `Custom Renderer`.

Comment: Hi there,would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here .

Comment: I'm trying to do [this override first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71427075/opening-target-blank-links-with-xamarin-forms-webview/71434614?noredirect=1#comment126363651_71434614) that has been suggested as a solution. I'm not sure where it should take place though.

Comment: Another issue. I update the Uri (with another one with a new query string), but the content in the WebView stays the same, although the content should change depending on the query. I even run Reload method for the WebView, but the content still stays the same. Should I change something in the Renderer?

Comment: Well, I found the answer. the suggested solution is wrong. `SetSupportMultipleWindows` should be set to ***false*** and not to ***true***, as it has been suggested. I did that changed and links now open!